# How can I limit the amount of data displayed when I import a csv file in a way allowing me to use all the data?

Tags: import, display

I am importing a large csv data file into Mathematica for analysis. The problem is that Mathematica insists on displaying all 2500 rows of data. This is only a small subset of a much larger project. Can I just read the file in and display the header like python and pandas. The reason I'm using Mathematica is that I need the Nonlinear Curve Fitting capability.

```
rbraw = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benhowe75/rubidium_hyperfine_414/\master/simple.csv", "Table"]
```

Comment: If you do something like `rbraw = Import[(* stuff *)];` (note the semicolon!), the output is suppressed. You can then use things like `Short[]` or `Shallow[]` to look at an elided version of the data.

Comment: Or `Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benhowe75/rubidium_
hyperfine_414/master/simple.csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice spectrum.

```
rbraw = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benhowe75/rubidium_hyperfine_414/master/simple.csv",
          "Dataset",
          HeaderLines -> 1];

rbraw[Map[Reverse]][ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500] &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can work like this: import the data, ending the `Import` expression with a semicolon so to not display the entire table.

```
rbraw = 
  Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benhowe75/rubidium_hyperfine_414/\master/simple.csv", "Dataset", 
  HeaderLines -> 1];
```

Then you can use the name of the dataset and specify the elements you want to display with the command. `rbraw[1;;10]`.  This will show the first ten values of the table, the same concept is used for more or less values.

[image]